# Bitly API Post request

Tags: javascript, json, rest, post

I'm trying to make a request to the Bitly API using the code below but I am receiving a 422 error message. I'm not using OAuth as it seems this is not required for single account users such as myself.

The documentation isn't too clear on how to make a request in this scenario.

```
function bitly() {
  var long_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
  var apiv4 = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten';
  var genericAccessToken = "xxxxx";

  var params = {
  method: "post",
  headers: {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + genericAccessToken, 
            "Content-Type": "application/json"},
  payload: {"group_guid": "string",
            "domain": "bit.ly",
            "long_url": long_url},
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiv4, params);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitly error:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

appears when payload/request content is not a JSON string.

For example in PHP do:

```
$headers =  [
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$param_bitly_token,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
];
                
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'header' => $headers,
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content'=> json_encode([
            'long_url' => $param_long_url,
            'title' => $param_title,
        ]),
    ],
]);
             
$response = file_get_contents('https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks', 0, $context);
```

Important bit here is **json_encode**, as for most other API-s it would be **http_build_query**

You have to send content as JSON string.